# What is the R equivalent of numpy "stride" indexing?

Tags: r

In numpy if you have an array x you can access it's elements with a 'stride' (i.e. skipping some inbetween) like so: x[::2]. How can you do this in R with a vector? I've searched all over the internet and couldn't find an answer to something so simple, kind of surprising.

EDIT:
I just realized that you could use seq(), but is there no built-in method for doing this?

Comment: The use of `seq()` in order to create the sequence of indexes is kind of "built-in" since it's from `base` R.

Comment: You can use `x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya so it turns out you just need to use 
`v[seq(to=length(v),by=stride)]`, just another quirk of R.

Though as @Igor F. mentioned they don't bother making it easier since array order is less important to statisticians. I imagine people are more likely to do something like `sample(v,as.integer(length(v)/stride))` without being so verbose of course.

Answer (score -1):

There is none, to my knowledge, but a hard-core R user (which I am not) would probably tell you that you are having a wrong approach. R is made for statistics, by statisticians. In their worldview, the order of the entries in an array or frame is irrelevant (or random), so there is no point in accessing them in a particular order.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, since it looks much like an opinion, which I disagree a lot. The `seq` function is the answer to the question and in no statistician worldview the entries order is always irrelevant (it might be sometimes of course). R provides a lot of functions to exploit the order of data in a dataset.